# Jmeter Per Process Results Analysis

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, perfmon

I have used jmeter for capturing the CPU and memory configurations of each component on my server using pid of that particular component.

I am able to get the results but i am not able to understand the results of the cpu and memory percentage of the each component.

I am bit confused how the jmeter is calculating the results.

Can anyone please explain me how to understand the results.

Please find the graph generated by jmeter when i calculated the cpu and memory percentage of tomcat.

[image: tomcat image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **multi-core** systems you can easily get percentages greater than 100% so the maximum number would be `number of cores * 100%`.

References:

- [What does >100% CPU utilization mean?](https://www.quora.com/What-does-100-CPU-utilization-mean)
- [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response.I am using 8 cores system. so according to my graph can i assume that my tomcat was taking sometimes 280% out of 800%. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Most probably yes, you need to count number of physical CPU (sockets) and multiply it by the number of cores per socket.

Answer (score 1):

CPU usage means how much of the CPU's total resources are being utilized at a given moment.

JMeter Perfmon metrics collector actually collects the server metrics (i.e CPU usage) for every second. In your graph, it just collects the CPU usage of process id "99696" for 11 minutes 17 seconds. You can easily match the JMeter results with your process CPU usage. For this, you can run the below commands on your server:

```
ps -p <pid> -o %cpu //This will return the CPU usage of the process while you run the command.
```

To check the CPU usage for every second, just run the below command and try to match with the JMeter results:

```
top -p <pid> //use your process ID like 99696 in <pid>
```

If you don't know the actual meaning of CPU usages of any process, please [check this](https://superuser.com/questions/675990/what-does-cpu-usage-for-a-process-actually-mean).

Comment: Thanks for your response jahan. Can you tell me what it is reffering on y-axis. Because when i calculated overall cpu and memory of my server it is giving percentage ranging from 0 to 100%. But when i calculating single process it is showing  above 100 which i am very confused what it is reffereing to.

Comment: This is the percentage of CPU used by this process. Resources used by that process in a percentage of the total CPU. Run the second commands and also run the JMeter Perfmon metrics collector together. It will match.

Comment: It's because of multi-core systems. Check these references to understand the CPU usages: https://superuser.com/questions/575202/understanding-top-command-in-unix/575330#575330 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/in-linux-top-command-what-are-us-sy-ni-id-wa-hi-si-and-st-for-cpu-usage. You can change the graph by using the "Force Maximum Y axis value to" under settings. Thanks

Comment: hi jahan, yeah i have used this force maximum y axis option, the values are restricting upto 100 but the graph is going beyond 100

Comment: I already gave my answer. That's because of multi-core systems. If you have 4 cores, then your cpu usages could be upto 400%. You can check the number of cores on your windows machine by using this command "echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%".

Comment: Thank a ton..I understood now.